# How to use socket io between 2 computers for a multiplayer game

Tags: node.js, socket.io, multiplayer

in frontend i have included

```
const socket=io("http://localhost:3000");
```

and in server side

```
const io=require('socket.io')();
const port=process.env.PORT||3000;
io.listen(port);

this works fine when the game is played from 2 windows in same computer
```

I tried changing the localhost to the ip address to connect to in the client side code

```
What changes must be made to make it playable from 2 different computers?

What changes must be made to the code?
```

Comment: With socket.io, you will have both clients connect to your server and your server will serve as the intermediary, passing data from one client to the other as desired.  You don't connect directly from one client to another client.